# Get Form ID from Input using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my form that I am creating from a php loop and what I'm trying to get is when the image is clicked i want to get the form id or all of the inputs names and values so that I can update my database.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `inventory` WHERE `active` = '1'");
    $i=1;
    while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo '<tr>
        <form id="'.$i++.'">
            <td style="width: 15%">'.$r['part_num'].'</td>
            <td style="width: 25%">'.$r['name'].'</td>
            <td style="width: 13%"><input type="text" name="sd_paint" value="'.$r['sd_paint'].'" class="inv_value"</td>
            <td style="width: 13%"><input type="text" name="sd_unpaint" value="'.$r['sd_unpaint'].'" class="inv_value"</td>
            <td style="width: 13%"><input type="text" name="ia_paint" value="'.$r['ia_paint'].'" class="inv_value"</td>
            <td style="width: 13%"><input type="text" name="ia_unpaint" value="'.$r['ia_unpaint'].'" class="inv_value"</td>
            <td style="width: 8%">
                <input type="image" src="pics/icons/edit.png" id="'.$r['inv_id'].'" class="submit_new_inv">
        </form>
                <img src="pics/icons/delete_inv.png" id="'.$r['inv_id'].'" class="edit_inv">
            </td>
        </tr>';
    }
```

And this is the javascript that Im using but this is just returning the first form:

```
$('.submit_new_inv').off().click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formID = document.forms[0].id;
    alert(formID);
});
```

sorry found the answer. You cannot wrap a form around table rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something similar to the following should work for you in the click event:

```
var myForm = $(this).closest('form');
alert(myForm.prop('id'));
```

You can find more information about closest at http://api.jquery.com/closest/.

Comment: This is what is returning [object Object]

Comment: Now its just returning "undefined"

Comment: In the markup, do you see the ID actually set?  Sorry, my PHP is rusty and I'm not equipped to debug here.

Comment: Yes, when i inspect the element it shows that the form id is incrementing by 1

Comment: If you check the underlying DOM element, var el = myForm.get(0), in the debugger, does the el variable have an ID?

Comment: so i found that you cannot wrap tr in forms rather you have to wrap either a table or user HTML5 form tag in the input

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.submit_new_inv').off().click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var formID = $(this).parents("form").prop("id");
alert(formID);
```

});

Comment: This is always returning "undefined" instead of the id

Comment: which jquery version used? 1.6 below, if 1.6 below,use var formID = $(this).parents("form").attr("id");

Comment: version jquery-2.1.1.js